# iOS: Push segues and the lifecyle of viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I just read an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969452/viewdidload-is-in-fact-called-every-time-there-is-a-segue-transition) on stackoverflow regarding the question of the lifecycle of view controllers when you use push segues (and a navigation controller). Since you use push segues, view controllers always call the viewDidLoad function, so a new instance is created.

My question is about deallocating the controllers which get popped from the navigation controller stack. In this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969452/viewdidload-is-in-fact-called-every-time-there-is-a-segue-transition) it is said that view controllers which are popped from the navigation stack and displayed, are deallocated when you push the next one.

Is that also true for ARC using projects? - and where is this done?