# How to create a custom UIStoryBoard

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

I would like to create my own UIStoryBoard and force the system to use it (inspired by [Jody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969452/viewdidload-is-in-fact-called-every-time-there-is-a-segue-transition)).

How can I do it?

Creating a class `@interface MyStoryboard : UIStoryboard` is not being invoked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were on the right path subclassing `UIStoryboard`: all you need to do now is to plug it into your application. The simplest way of doing it is in your application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

MyStoryboard.h

```
@interface MyStoryboard : UIStoryboard
-(id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
@end
```

MyStoryboard.m

```
@implementation MyStoryboard

-(id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSLog(@"Instantiating: %@", identifier);
    return [super instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
}

@end
```

MyAppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [MyStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"<identifier-of-your-storyboard>" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

With this code in place, you will see calls of `NSLog` every time the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method is called.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it in the next hour and get back.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. Now I will try to implement the caching solution and see if viewDidLoad is not being invoked twice

Comment: I think they have plugged this hole, and this no longer works.